# Renaming postgres parent table with child partitions

Tags: postgresql

is it ok to rename a parent table from which partitioned child tables are based ?

For example if I have

```
CREATE TABLE demos_qa (
demo_id int,
demo_date VARCHAR,
demo_text TEXT)
PARTITION BY RANGE (trxn_post_dt);

CREATE TABLE demos_2022 PARTITION OF demos_qa
FOR VALUES FROM ('2022-01-01') TO ('2023-01-01');

CREATE TABLE demos_2021 PARTITION OF demos_qa
FOR VALUES FROM ('2021-01-01') TO ('2022-01-01');

CREATE TABLE demos_2020 PARTITION OF demos_qa
FOR VALUES FROM ('2020-01-01') TO ('2021-01-01');
```

and I bulk load the partition tables.

I now want to rename the parent table from `demo_qa` to `demo`. Can I do that and will things work as normal without having to change the definitions of the partition tables ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [this will work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f8b48ea1a22598c4ee590c63fbc6c8bf).

The partitions won't be renamed though, in case you expected that.

Comment: Also thanks for the dbfiddle link. That's a cool service for helping one test database code out.